# How to safely retrieve the value of a Ruby method that might not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I thought I understood how `try` works, but I'm getting an undefined method error:

```
unknown_object.try(:some_method).try(:get_value)
```

I found in the [documentation for `try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) that it only rescues from an undefined method error if the object is nil. In my case, I know my object is not nil, but I'm not sure if it has the method I need.

How can I safely retrieve (and chain) the methods together so that I don't get undefined method errors?

Comment: Its a rail method.. I think you should tag it as *ruby on rails* also.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a Ruby method. Oops.

Comment: I got it previously....

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you're looking for was implemented in [Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md):

> `Object#try` will now return `nil` instead of raise a `NoMethodError` if the
>   receiving object does not implement the method, but you can still get
>   the old behavior by using the new `Object#try!`.

Here's the Rails 4 source code for the new `try`:

```
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    yield self
  else
    public_send(*a, &b) if respond_to?(a.first)
  end
end
```

The only difference is `if respond_to?(a.first)`.

Answer (score 3):

`try` works as expected only when you call it on nil object. Since your's is a valid object, I think what you need is respond to

```
if unknown_object.respond_to?(:some_method)
  unknown_object.some_method.get_value
end
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer in fact it is more generally correct. But for Rails 4 folks Stefan is dead on